# Mobile device landscape mode show not supportable message

Tags: jquery, html, responsive-design

I am creating responsive Website which is responsive on browser but when it gets open in mobile landscape mode Not supportive mode message should display,I achieved this with following code but it's getting applied on desktop as well

```
 // On Orientation Change
 $(window).resize( function(){
 var h = $(window).height();
 var w = $(window).width();

 if ( w < 600) {
 if(w > h) {
 // Small Screen Landscape Rules
 $('#about').css('display','none');
 $('.landscapemsg').css('display','block');
 }else{
 // Small Screen Portrait Rules
 $('#about').css('display','block');
  $('.landscapemsg').css('display','none');
 }
 // All Small Screen Rules
 }

 });
 }else{
    // Not a mobile device
     $('#about').css('display','block');
 }
```

Please help me to apply this thing only on mobile device

Comment: Have you read up on CSS media queries?  Start there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must first detect your device,
Maby this javascript code help you.

```
var device =  navigator.userAgent;
    var patern = 'Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini|avantgo|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile';
    var found = device.match( patern );
    if (found != null) {
        // this is mobile device
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**in your .js file:**

```
var appCheck = document.URL.indexOf( 'http://' ) === -1 && document.URL.indexOf( 'https://' ) === -1;

if(appCheck)
{
//your mobile content will goes here. 
}
```

**Note:**
document.URL.indexOf( 'http://' ) === -1 && document.URL.indexOf( 'https://' ) === -1;

this code fails for browser.